# Random word from a dictionnary GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, random, jlabel

I am working on a game that selects a random word and the user have to find it in less than 7 mistakes, if he makes 7 mistakes he loses, if he makes less than 7 mistakes another word is given and his mistakes are kept. in the end the score is given.

I have a txt file dictionnary, and I wan't to know how to select a word from it and put it in a variable, then show this word hidden in stars ***** in a JLabel

thank you

Comment: I'd suggest using a random number generator.

Comment: How else would you propose to pick a "random" word?  (Of course, the trick is finding a complete word, vs just starting in the middle of one because that's where the random number took you.  That will require that you exert your thinking muscles a bit.)

Comment: Have you read the file? In what structure do you have the list of words?

Comment: I didn't read the file I don't know how, this is the first time I use random in java hot licks, what do you mean in what structure ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @HotLicks means is to use the `Random` class or `Math.random()`, both of which can create a random number. Let say you want to create random number between 0 and 99 inclisive. You would do something like this

```
Random random = new Random();
int randIndex random.nextInt(100);
```

What the above does is give you a random index. We will use this random index to select a word.

No to actually get the set of words, you need to get them into some kind of data structure, so you don't have to keep reading the file over and over. Let's say your file looks like this, every word on its own line

```
Abba
Zabba 
Youre
My
Only
Friend
```

What you want to do is store those words into a data structure like a `List`. To that you need to read the file line by line, while adding each line to the `List`

```
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt"));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine().trim()) != null) {
        wordList.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now the `wordList` has all the words from your file. And the `randIndex` variable holds a random index from the list. So you could do

```
String randWord = wordList.get(randIndex);
```

Of course though in the vary first piece of code in the this answer, you need to know the size of the list, before you can decide what number the random number should do up to. So after you populate the list, you would do something like this

```
Random random = new Random();
int randIndex = random.netInt(wordList.size());
```

So every time you need a new word, just generate a new random number and use that numbers to get a word from the list at that index.

---

Please see [Basic I/O trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) for more help with reading files.

Comment: Peeskillet thank you so much !!! that was exactly what I needed, really helpful, I didn't know anything about I/O basics so I sought to understand BufferedReader, and it did the magic !! I still don't know why this was selected as offtopic and had  -1, thank you, you are the best